# Update only time from my Datetime column (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a column with dates in my table:

```
2022-09-18 00:00:00.000
2023-09-18 00:00:00.000
2025-09-18 00:00:00.000
```

I want to update only time of that date after id key 38
ex)

```
id 39 -> 2022-09-18 23:59:59. 
id 40 -> 2023-09-18 23:59:59.
 ...
```

Is there any query to update only time for a `datetime` column?

Comment: This is covered by the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, but many products have their own functions instead. However, `datetime` is not an ANSI/ISO SQL data type, so I suspect you want a product specific answer - but for which dbms?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which DBMS you're using but in MariaDB/MySQL I would try the following:

```
update date_table
set date_col = date_col + interval 1 day - interval 1 second
where id > 38
```

Comment: ANSI SQL: `+ interval'1' day - interval'1' second`.

Comment: MySQL does also implement the ANSI SQL syntax. I'd use that, more portable code with almost no effort.